# Automatic save files without show save dialog in C# web browser Control

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a C# window application, which contains a web browser control (winform).
When I click on the Click button I want to save the running web page in HTML only without showing the save as dialog.

Note:-

I don't want to use `webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();`